# How do general coordinate transformations fix components of the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, string-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

In studying string theory, one sees the argument that we can gauge-fix the worldsheet metric to become the Minkowski metric. The argument usually goes that general coordinate transformations (GCTs) fix two components, and Weyl transformations fix one. Moving on to an arbitrary number of dimensions ($d$), I have been trying to understand how GCTs can fix $d$ components of the metric, but I have been unable to so far. What I have found is that under $x^\mu \to \bar x^\mu = x^\mu + \xi^\mu,$ we have $\bar g_{\mu\nu}(\bar x)=g_{\mu\nu}(\bar x) -(\partial_\mu \xi_\nu +\partial_\nu \xi_\mu).$ However, I fail to see how the $\delta g$ term could fix only $d$ components (I am aware that $\xi_\mu$ has only four components, but it seems that the whole term could potentially allow us to fix more than $d$ components of the metric). If anyone could help to clarify, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Daniel Waters: Just to be clear: Do you assume that $d=2$?

Comment: No, I did not. That was just to illustrate the motivating example. I made an edit to clarify.

Comment: That appears to be essentially the fact that $n$ equations with $m<n$ unknowns are generically [overdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system).